# Trying to understand the structure of "fear the walking dead".

Tags: word-choice

Is it like "fear of walking dead" or as in "I order you to fear the walking dead"? Can one paraphrase this phrase? Isn't this a so peculiar naming?

Comment: I think this is purely a a language question.

Answer (score 1):

As you are no doubt aware, this is called [Imperative form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood) (sometimes referred to as *mood*). It is used to give advice, an order, a warning, an exhortation, etc.

[Imperative Form](http://www.englishbaby.com/lessons/grammar/imperative_form)

> "Stop!," "Come here!," and "Look out!" are all examples of the imperative form.
>
> You can use the imperative form to give an order, a warning, or some advice.

Here it seems to be an exhortation and a warning, similar to [Be afraid....Be very afraid.](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071211201009AAwTe5u)

As a side-note, I don't believe either of the series use the term [“Walking Dead”](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109291/what-are-all-the-different-names-survivors-have-called-zombies/109296#109296) within the program except [with reference to themselves](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109291/what-are-all-the-different-names-survivors-have-called-zombies/109296#109296), the survivors. As the plot develops, it becomes apparent that the ones to truly fear are the survivors, who in their struggle to exist in this post-apocalyptic scenario are a danger to themselves and each other.